# MPMoviePlayerController in Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to know if it's possible to have a MoviePlayer in portrait mode.

Thanks for your help.

T.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `[moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];`
" API your application will be rejected from Apple Store

Answer (score 1):

You can. See Erica Sadun's article at
http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/11/the-joys-of-vertical-audio.html.

But note that about  method for doing this  is undocumented by Apple and therefore not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerController (extend)
-(void)setOrientation:(int)orientation animated:(BOOL)value;
@end

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUR];
[moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
if (moviePlayer)
{
        [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Implement above code. You will get what you want.

Hope that helps.

Sagar.

Check out following question.
It has the same solutions.

[playing video in custom size screen - view in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422930/playing-video-in-custom-size-screen-view-in-iphone)

Comment: my app was rejected with this extension. =\