# how to Play movie in portrait mode

Tags: iphone

Can i play movie in portrait  mode?If yes than how to play?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the MPMoviePlayerController explicitly, you can load the movie into a UIWebView. That will launch the movie in portrait mode, with the usual movie player controls. Credits go to this [blog post](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/simple-way-to-play-mp3-audio-files).

Here's a code snippet:

```
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)] autorelease];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: urlToMovie];
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
[request release];
```

Here the webView instance is initialized as a 1x1 pixel element, and is not added as a sub-view. When it loads the URL request of the movie, it will automatically fill the entire screen and you'll see the movie play in portrait mode.

Note: it seems like it requires iPhone OS 3.1 (or higher) for videos to play in UIWebView.

Answer (score 4):

Rotate the video 90° in your video editing software.

Comment: Freakin genious, why hasn't someone suggested this before? By far the most simple solution.

Comment: unless the video's aspect ratio is portrait originally

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before and is solved here:

[MPMoviePlayerController in Portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374558/mpmovieplayercontroller-in-portrait-mode)

be warned that it uses private api's

Comment: you are right.  It looks like you might have to roll your own movie player

Comment: @coneybeare & @ceejayoz checkout my answer added their.

Answer (score 1):

try to implement this in your code.

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerController (extend)
-(void)setOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)value;
@end

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:animated:)])
    [moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
if (moviePlayer)
{
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I've edited it such that it will no longer crash if Apple decides to remove the private API (it will just play landscape instead)