# Can i play video in portrait mode?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody explain me how to play video in portrait mode in iphone device. It will be very helpful to if you provide some sample code for referance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423610/how-to-play-movie-in-portrait-mode

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show your movie in portrait mode using MPMoviePlayerController, it is better
to get your video rotated by 90 degree so that it always play in Landscape mode but appears to the user as it is playing in Portrait mode...

I have gone through so many tricks and found the above as best alternate.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to rotate the video so that if it was being played in landscape and the device was turned to portrait, it would be oriented correctly. From there, you could disable the controls (so tapping the screen doesn't bring up the video controls) if you don't need them. That way the user wouldn't know that the player is actually landscape.

Edit: Try this code from this thread over at [iPhoneDevSDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2146-can-you-force-movie-play-portrait-mode.html); I don't know if it will work since I haven't used it, though:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

[moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

**Edit: Whoops! As I read further in the thread, Apple considers that method a private API and will probably reject your app for using it. You could try, though.**

Comment: My requirement do not needed the controls over the video, but how can i rotate the video (CGAffineTransformMakeRotation() can do this?). Am new to this field, can you provide some sample code for this.

Comment: I tried this - Apple *will* reject your App if you want to submit with this in! We had to settle for landscape mode!

Comment: Apple did NOT reject my app, but it crashes in iOS 4.0 so i'll have to change it anyway.

Comment: Hay kevin the question is something different then what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to be in portrait orientation? Video itself you can rotate any which-way when you're creating it; the overlay controls, though, you can't really do anything with within the boundaries of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is to use UIWebView to play the video, as it supports both orientations.
Here's some sample code (note: the webview will spawn a new modal view for the video to play in, so I size it at zero x zero):

```
if( !webView )
{
   self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];   
   [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/movie.m4v"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```