# How To Play Movie In iPhone Portrait Mode Half Screen

Tags: iphone

Could anyone tell me how I can play movie in portrait mode half screen?

I can't use `[mMoviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO]` API
because it is a private API (Apple will reject our application if we use their private API).

Answer (score 0):

There are already two solutions on the site...
a simple search reveled both... and your question as well :P

[Solution 1 by - pythonquick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423610/how-to-play-movie-in-portrait-mode)

[Solution 2 by - John (an others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967932/can-i-play-video-in-portrait-mode)