# How to play video in portrait mode in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating a movie appliction in iphone/ipod .i have added a video to it . when i run it in simulator it runs properly in portrait mode.But when i run my app in ipod it opens a blank video and in landscape mode .but in  simulator when i click on play my video directly plays in portrait mode and in ipod it opens a blank video in landscape mode which i want in portrait mode

This is my code for video:

```
-(IBAction)video1:(id)sender
{
    NSBundle *bundle =[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviepath =[bundle pathForResource:@"CRY CRY - 90 Sec Video" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *movieURL =[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviepath]retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
```

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423610/how-to-play-movie-in-portrait-mode

Comment: Another duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967932/can-i-play-video-in-portrait-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of iOS is your iPod running? Version 3.x will always open videos in landscape mode, version 4.x will open videos in the current orientation.

Comment: my ipod is of 4.0 version but then too it is opening in landscape mode

Comment: please simon help me in solving this problem