# MPMoviePlayerController should only in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using the MPMoviePlayerController in my application to play videos. My application is working only in portrait mode. and I want application video should only play in landscape mode only. So please can any one suggest how i do this. Right now my video is playing in Portrait mode.

Answer (score 3):

For doing this, You need to subclass the `MPMoviePlayerController` class.

```
@interface yourMovie:MPMoviePlayerController
{
}
@end
```

and you need to implement the `shouldAutoRotate` method in the implementation and return only landscape mode

```
@implementation yourMovie

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
@end
```

And you need to create `yourMovie` instance instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`

Comment: Thanks for Quick Answer. But its not working in iOS 6. Please can you provide me for iOS 6. thx

Comment: @MiteshKhatri: I used the same code for iOS 6. Also check return yes from the shouldRotate method of the parentview in which you are creating the moviePlayer

Comment: I checked and the application supported orientation is only Portrait and I want only player in landscape. I also tried above code but it not works for me. thx

Comment: @MiteshKhatri: please check this link, it may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374558/mpmovieplayercontroller-in-portrait-mode?rq=1

Comment: Hi, @Midhun MP, I tried everything but its did not worked for me. So please can you suggest me how I can display video in landscape mode when application is only in Portrait mode. Thanks

Comment: You are to subclass `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and not `MPMoviePlayerController` to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code in your MPMoviePlayerController,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Instead of `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` you can use `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` also...

Comment: Thanks for Quick Answer. But its not working in iOS 6. Please can you provide me for iOS 6. thx

Comment: In xcode there is a option under "Summary" is 'supported Device Orientation' in that select the landscape option.... i am not sure abt this in ios6... but try this,..

Comment: Its working fine in iOS 5 but does not in iOS 6. So if you have any idea then let me know.