# Portrait video to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, video, ios6

I am aware questions like this one may already be out there but for the sake of others like me I will go ahead and ask

I have a app that is set to only allow portrait orientation but this setting affects my videos as I would like only the videos to be able to play in landscape also. Is there a method I can add unto my .m file to make this work? Here is my code;

```
 #import "BIDVideosViewController.h"

 @interface BIDVideosViewController ()


 @end

 @implementation BIDVideosViewController

 @synthesize moviePlayer ;


 @synthesize tableList;


 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }


 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
 [table setDelegate:self];
 [table setDataSource:self];
 [self.view addSubview:table];
 tableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gangan",@"SwimGood",@"German Ice", nil];

 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 return [tableList count];
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *DisclosureButtonIdentifier = @"DisclosurebutotonIdentifier";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DisclosureButtonIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonIdentifier];
 }

 NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
 NSString *rowString = [tableList objectAtIndex:row];
 cell.textLabel.text = rowString;

 return cell;
 }




 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
{
    NSBundle *str = [tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([str isEqual:@"Gangan"])
    {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *thePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Gangan" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *theurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];

        [moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];

        [moviePlayer play];
    }
    else if ([str isEqual:@"SwimGood"])
    {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *thePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"SwimGood" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *theurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
        [moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];

        [moviePlayer play];

    }
    else if ([str isEqual:@"German Ice"])
    {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *thePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"German Ice" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *theurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
        [moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];

        [moviePlayer play];
    }

   }
   }
   @end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPMoviePlayerController should only in landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011266/mpmovieplayercontroller-should-only-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller .m file, you should have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

There you can return `YES` for supported orientations, which will enable you to rotate video.

Also not that if you use UINavigationController, this aproach wont work, unless all views managed by `UINavigationController` implement `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` the same way.

Also in your Targets -> "You Project" -> Summary, you can set supported orientations.

Edit:
go [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientation) an look for UIInterfaceOrientation. There you have constants you need.

I would write it like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
       return YES;  
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
       return YES; 
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
       return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks..say i wanted to use 'lanscapeleft' and 'landscaperight' how do i write that, could you please amend the answer :) thanks @MartinBerger