# Objective C/Xcode enable landscape only in video

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

How can I enable landscape only in video player while rest of app is only in portrait view?

Answer (score -1):

Subclass MPMoviePlayerViewController and implement

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
}
```

Duplicate of:
[MPMoviePlayerController should only in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011266/mpmovieplayercontroller-should-only-in-landscape-mode)

> In iOS 6 and later, your app supports the interface orientations
>   defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override
>   the supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of
>   supported orientations.

Comment: It doesn't work in iOS7

Comment: You need to research autorotate methods for yourself based on which version of iOS you are using.  Autorotate methods are different on iOS 7 vs. 8 or 6.

Comment: Subclass MPMoviePlayerViewController instead.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I subclass it in my.h file like this: 

`#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface PlayerViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController {}`

and in my .m file:
`@implementation PlayerViewController
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
} `

Any ideas? I also try disabling portrait view in xcode gui.